# Can we add Icons on the right side of the AppBar by Trailing or SizedBox ? WHY & Why not?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfUD9.png)Why I can't use the row and trailing and sized box section?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using `AppBar` `actions` like

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [Icon(Icons.ac_unit)], ///here
      ),
      body: Text("Body"),
    );
```

Overview of AppBar

[image]

For more on [AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

Comment: thank you so much for your help❤

Comment: Glad to help you out.